# Issue with styles in Firefox, IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, wordpress-theming

I'm having troubles with my new website in Wordpress. I have selected a theme and I have overwritten some styles. I have used also Visual Composer. In Google Chrome it's perfect or with some small pixel perfect, but when I see it on Firefox all is a mess! xO I was searching and checking each detail but I couldn't find nothing, so..I think that more heads can thinking more efficiently.

The site is [Crescor Travel](http://dev.crescortravel.com/)

Here a screenshot with error:
[image: Error in Firefox]

I think that the error can be in margins. Somebody know if there's problem with margin?

The CSS code is...

```css
/**
* LAYOUT CONTENT
*/
section.content { padding: 0; }


/**
* TYPOGRAPHIC
*/
*, body { font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif !important; }

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #202226 !important;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3rem !important;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 2.25rem !important;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 2rem !important;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

strong { color: #202226; }

article {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

i {
    font-style: normal !important;
}


/**
* HEADER SECTION
*/
.title_section {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.caption_section {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    color: #747980;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 71px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.fullscreen-container,
.fullwidthbanner-container {
  height: 100% !important;
}

body div.title_container {
    margin-top: 66%!important;
    margin-left: -22.5%!important;
}

.subheader-title-holder { 
    padding: 0 30% 0 9.5% !important; 
}

.main-title {
    text-align: left!important;
    font-weight: 300!important;
    font-size: 3rem!important;
    margin-left: -18px!important;
}

.main-title span { font-weight: bold !important; }

h1.title_page {
    color: #fff!important;
    margin-bottom: 22px !important;
    line-height: 54px!important;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 2px!important;
}
h1.title_page strong {
    font-size: 3rem !important;
    color: #fff!important;
    font-weight: 600!important;
    letter-spacing: 1px!important;
}
p.caption_page {
    font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    line-height: 36px !important;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px!important;
    margin: 30px 0 60px !important;
}

div#slide-4-layer-2 {
    margin-top: 110px !important;
    margin-left: -70%!important;
    width: 170px;
    color: #E74C3C!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    background-color: #fff!important;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
}

.bruno-subheader-wraper { 
    overflow: visible!important; 
}


/**
* NAV SECTION
*/
#bruno-head {
    z-index: 999;
}
.dpr-fullwidth {
  padding-left: 8.4%!important;
  padding-right: 8.4%!important;
}
.imageLogo .logo-default {
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
    height: 15px !important;
    width: 138px !important;
}

body .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper li:last-child a {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
    padding: 6px 0 !important;
}

body .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper li:last-child a:hover { background-color: #ea314a!important; }

body .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper li:last-child a .menu-title:hover { color: #fff!important; }

body div#bruno-navigation-wrapper .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.root a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    border: none!important;
}
body .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.root a .menu-title:hover { color: #000; }

body #bruno-navigation-wrapper.bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.root.current-menu-item a { color: #EA314A!important; }

body .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper li:last-child a .menu-title { color: #E74C3C !important; }

.imageLogo .logo-sticky { padding-top: 26px; }

.sf-menu li a {
    padding: 36px 0 36px 0;
    font-size: 0.75rem !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
body #bruno-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.root a:hover,
.current-menu-item a {
    font-weight: bold!important;
    color: #fff!important;
}

body #bruno-navigation-wrapper .bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.root a:hover,
.current-menu-item a {
    color: #000!important;
}

.sf-menu li { margin-left: 18px; }

.top-navigation ul li:last-child a {
    margin-top: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 45px;
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding: 8px!important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold!important;
}

body .submenu li.childmenu { background-color: #fff; }

body .submenu li.childmenu a:hover { background: #fff!important; }

body .submenu li.childmenu a .menu-title { color: #333333!important; }

.top-navigation .submenu li.childmenu:last-child a {
    margin: 0!important;
    border: none!important;
    padding: 13px 16px!important;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    height: initial!important;
    width: initial!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    text-align: left!important;
    padding-top: 13px!important;
}

.bruno-sticky-navigation-wrapper ul li:last-child a {
    margin-top: 12px !important;
}

body #bruno-navigation-wrapper .top-navigation ul li:last-child a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #EA314A!important;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.icon-menu { 
    color: #fff!important; 
}

#bruno-navigation-wrapper .sf-menu li.current-menu-item  a {
    color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #fff !important;
}


/**
*   CONTENT
*/
#bruno-mainbody { padding: 0; }

.bruno-page {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: -90px;
}

#talk_to_us h3 {
    font-weight: normal!important;
    color: #202226!important;
}

#talk_to_us a { margin-top: 50px; }

body .about_us .vc_single_image-wrapper:before {
    background-color: #E74C3C!important;
    top: 48%;
}

body div#second_row_about div.wpb_column div.vc_single_image-wrapper:before { 
    top: 58%!important;
}


/**
* BANNER SECTION
*/
.banner_section {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 78.5%;
  margin: -10% auto 0 auto!important;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 90px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 32px;
}

.banner_section .wpb_column {
  margin-top: -58px!important;
}

.banner_section span { color: #202226!important; }

#first_column_banner p span {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #202226 !important;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#first_column_banner p:last-child { font-size: 14px; }

#first_column_banner { padding: 50px 35px 0 35px; }
#second_column_banner { padding: 60px 35px 0 0; }
#third_column_banner { padding: 62px 40px 0 0; }

#first_column_banner,
#second_column_banner,
#third_column_banner {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

#second_column_banner span,
#third_column_banner span {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}
.banner_section h2 {
    color: #202226!important;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.banner_section p {
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #747980;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px !important;
}
.banner_section .btn_white { border: 1px solid #e8e8e8; }
.Default-minus {
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    color: #E74C3C;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.section_service .vc_column-inner {
    padding: 100px 17%!important;
}

.section_service h2 { font-style: normal!important; }

.section_service i {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #EB374A;
    font-style: normal!important;
}

.section_service hr {
    width: 11%;
    float: left;
}


/**
* SOLUTIONS SECTION
*/
#solution {
    margin-top: 147px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.vc_box_shadow { box-shadow: 0 12px 90px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.1)!important; }

.solution_left .block_solution {
    margin: 100px;
}

.block_solution hr {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    color: #E7E8EB!important;
    border: 1px solid #E7E8EB;
}

.take_off .vc_single_image-wrapper:before { content: none!important; }

.solution_right .block_solution {
    margin: 124px 180px 124px 110px;
}

h2.title_block_solution {
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2rem!important;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p.caption_block_solution {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.solution_right,
.solution_left { margin-top: 130px !important; }

.solution_left .vc_single_image-wrapper:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 312px;
    height: 312px;
    background-color: #f6fafb;
}

.solution_left .vc_single_image-wrapper:before,
.solution_right .vc_single_image-wrapper:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 312px;
    height: 312px;
    background-color: #f6fafb;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: -10%;
}

.solution_left .vc_single_image-wrapper:before {
  top: 49%;
}
.solution_right .vc_single_image-wrapper:before {
  top: 35%;
}


/**
* PARTNERS SECTION
*/
div#partners { margin-top: 70px; }

#partners_logos {
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

#partners_logos .vc_inner img { width: 130px; }

#partners .wpb_content_element { margin-bottom: 90px; }

#partners_mobile .vc_inner { text-align: center; }


/**
* CALL TO ACTION
*/
.call_to_action {
    width: 120%!important;
    margin-left: -10%!important;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 100px 115px 60px;
    background-color: #292929;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #EA314A 0%, #E84C3C 100%);
    z-index: 10!important;
}
body p.call_to_action_white strong a {
    color: #fff!important;
    font-weight: 600!important;
}
.call_to_action_white {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}


/**
* WIDGETS SECTION
*/
.vc_wp_custommenu .menu li {
    padding: 0!important;
    background: none!important;
    border-left: none!important;
}
.vc_wp_custommenu .menu li a {
    font-weight: 600!important;
    line-height: 32px!important;
    color: #747980!important;
}

.box-title span {
    text-transform: none!important;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

.stripe:before {
    content: "----";
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #E74C3C;
}

.box-title span:before {
    content: "----";
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #E74C3C;
}

#bruno-footer .box.widget_nav_menu ul li a {
    color: #747980;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#bruno-footer-wrap { 
    padding: 90px 0 100px 0; 
}

#bruno-footer .box-title { margin-bottom: 10px!important; }

.footer-middle .box-title {
    padding-top: 16px;
}

.footer-middle .menu-footer-menu-container { margin-top: -6px; }

.textwidget { 
    color: #747980; 
}

#bruno-footer .box p {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/**
*   FOOTER
*/
.bruno-copyrights-text {
    color: #89898B;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -6px !important;
}

#bruno-footer-wrap {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.widget_nav_menu { margin-top: -16px; }

#nav_menu-2 { padding-left: 150px; }

#bruno-footer-wrap hr {
    width: 83.2%;
    border: 1px solid #e7e8eb;
}

#menu-footer-menu .current-menu-item a {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    color: #747980 !important;
}

#built_by_text {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #89898b;
}

#built_by_text a {
    color: #e74c3c!important;
    font-weight: 600;
}


/**
* BUTTONS
*/
a.btn_white {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 19px 50px !important;
    border-radius: 60px;
    color: #E74C3C!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

body a.btn_white:hover {
    background-color: #EA314A;
    color: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: none;
}

a.btn_white:active { box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

a.btn_red {
    width: 170px;
    background-color: #E74C3C!important;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #EA314A 0%, #E84C3C 100%);
    color: #fff!important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
a.btn_red:hover {
  border-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea314a 0%, #e84c3c 100%);
}
a.btn_red:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ea314a 0%, #e84c3c 100%);
}


/**
*   ELEMENTALS
*/
.none_padding_right { padding-right: 0 !important; }

.transparent { background-color: transparent !important; }

.vc_column-inner { padding: 0 !important; }

body .vc_custom_1500523474242 { background-color: #fff !important; }

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] { font-family: 'dpricomoon'!important; }
[class^="ts-"], [class*=" ts-"] { font-family: 'Crescor'!important; }

.list_block_solution { list-style: none; }

.list_block_solution i { margin-right:20px; color: #E64C3B; }

.gform_footer { text-align: center; }

.gfield_label { 
    display: none!important; 
}

body .gform_footer .gform_button {
    width: 170px!important;
    background-color: #E74C3C!important;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #EA314A 0%, #E84C3C 100%);
    color: #fff!important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    margin-top: 20px!important;
}

textarea, input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=www], input[type=tel], input[type=date], input[type=number], select {
    background: #F6FAFB;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif !important;
    color: #202226;
    padding: 22px 18px !important;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

input[type=text]:active,
input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    border: 1px solid #e7e8eb;
    height: 42px;
}

#send_message hr {
    width: 50px;
    color: #E7E8EB!important;
}

.gfield_description,
.validation_message { display: none; }

.gfield_error {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    border: none!important;
}

.gform_wrapper li.gfield_error input:not([type=radio]):not([type=checkbox]):not([type=submit]):not([type=button]):not([type=image]):not([type=file]),
.gform_wrapper li.gfield_error textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e74c3c !important;
    background-color: #fff!important;
}

#mCSB_1 { background-color: #fff!important; }

#bruno-mobile-menu ul li a { color: #333!important; }

.icon-prev,
.icon-next { display: none !important; }

#bruno-mobile-menu { background-color: #fff!important; }

#bruno-mobile-menu #close-mobile-menu {
  left: 20px;
  top: 4px;
  color: #333333!important;
}

div.parallax { background-attachment: unset; }

.validation_error {
  border: none!important;
  color: #e74c3c!important;
}

.list_block_solution li { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

It seems like a problem with the margins in firefox. A different behavior I think...

Can you help me to diagnostic what hell is happing?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Could you provide the styles you changed?

Comment: You need to post some code most users will not bother clicking on your link and trying to figure out what you need. Let us see what you have tried and describe the problem in some detail so we can help. my initial guess would be you are using some vendor specific styles that are unsupported or do not have appropriate fallbacks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kolunar I have explain a bit more the issue. Thank you for suggest!

Comment: What's up with all the `!important`s in there? Is this your code? If so, you should refactor so those aren't necessary - because you will continue to have problems.

Comment: Do you think that? Sorry about my bad code. I am still a bit newbie. I'll do, but while, I need resolve this issue on firefox. Any help? @JakeParis

Answer (score 0):

Jean it looks fine to me. Maybe it's an outdated version of Firefox?

[image]